# Passport LocalStrategy not handling bad credentials

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I am trying to set up basic authentication with Passport.js LocalStrategy but I am re-routed to the successRedirect `(res.redirect('../public/index.html')` even with incorrect username/password entered in the login form.

My `db.query()` calls are returning correct results on other routes so I think the issue is in another part of the code but I just don't see where at this stage.

My understanding of the use of "user" vs. "username" in the LocalStrategy is hazy and potentially where the issue lies?

If any one is able to spot the issue i'd be most grateful.

(Note, I have stripped back the snippet below to remove the hash and crypto/bcrypt features just to get the bare bones working before implementing some basic security methods)

```
const express = require('express');
const loginRouter = express.Router();
const path = require('path');
const passport = require('passport');
const session = require('express-session');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local');
const db = require('../db/db');

// Define session (update secret to env variable once working). 
loginRouter.use(
  session({
    secret: "D53gxl41G",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
  })
);

loginRouter.use(passport.initialize());
loginRouter.use(passport.session());

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function (username, password, done) {
  db.query('SELECT * FROM customers WHERE username = $1', [username], function(err, user) {
    if (err) return done(err);
    if (!user) return done(null, false);
    if (user.password != password) return done(null, false);
    return done(null, user);
    });  
  })
);

// GET log in page
loginRouter.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.status(200).sendFile(path.resolve('./public/auth.html'));
});

// POST form submission w/passport authentication. Not showing errors even with incorrect username/passwords.
loginRouter.post('/', passport.authenticate('local', 
  { failureRedirect: '/' }), 
  (req, res) => {
    res.redirect('../public/index.html');
  }
);

module.exports = loginRouter;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT will return an object. That object has a property **rows** listing any matching row from the database. In your code, that object is **user**. And to get the one item matching the SELECT query you would do **user.rows[0]**. Comparing the password:

```
if (user.rows[0].password != password) return done(null, false);
```

I suggest that you rename user to **res** then create a variable such as:

```html
db.query('SELECT * FROM customers WHERE username = $1', [username], function (err, res) {
    const user = res.rows[0]
    if (err) return done(err);
    if (!user) return done(null, false);
    if (user.password != password) return done(null, false);
    return done(null, user);
  });
```